# SRFax NameError: name 'suds' is not defined

Tags: python

I've been using a community-made fax api (https://github.com/raparri01/srfax-api-python) in Python but I've been stuck on this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "...srfax_api_python\srfax\srfax.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.client = suds.client.Client(self.url)
NameError: name 'suds' is not defined
```

I basically used the code below:

```
from srfax_api_python.srfax import srfax

srfax_client = srfax.SRFax(<SRFAX_ACCESS_ID>,
                           <SRFAX_ACCESS_PWD>,
                           caller_id=<SRFAX_CALLER_ID>,
                           sender_email=<SRFAX_SENDER_EMAIL>)

fax_id = srfax_client.queue_fax('+11234567', '/path/to/fax/file')
status = srfax_client.get_fax_status(fax_id)
```

I've used pip to install suds-jurko, which was noted in the requirements.txt file of the repo. I also changed the name of my copy of the repo to srfax_api_python because I couldn't import srfax-api-python. Also, the error occurs when I create srfax_client object, and the file that I create this object in is in the same folder as the srfax_api_python folder. Could someone point me in the right direction?

All help is greatly appreciated